# redirect jersey logging filter to logback

Tags: java, logging, jersey, logback

I use Jersey for my web service and I configure my web.xml file with logging filter for both request and response filtering

Jersey uses java.util.logging API

I would like to know how to redirect the log to logback

apparently this doesn't work:

```
<logger name="com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter" level="DEBUG">
```

could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I try to use SLF4JBridgeHandler to bridge JUL to SLF4J and I've got a lot of uninteresting log in my log file

http://blog.cn-consult.dk/2009/03/bridging-javautillogging-to-slf4j.html

I need to filter but it seems to work fine